# How to use Rspec to mock an array push

Tags: ruby, rspec

How do you mock a push into a class array variable using Rspec?  Here is an over-simplified example:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
  def initialize
    @bar = []
  end
end

def some_method(foo)
  foo.bar << "a"
end
```

Say I want to write a spec for some_method that "it should push a new value to bar".  How do I do that?

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.should_receive(WHAT GOES HERE???).with("a")
some_method(foo)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why mock anything? You only need to mock something when it is a dependency that you are trying to isolate from what you are actually trying to test. In your case, you seem to be trying to verify that calling `some_method` results in adding an item to a property of an object you passed in. You can simply test it directly:

```
foo = Foo.new
some_method(foo)
foo.bar.should == ["a"]

foo2 = Foo.new
foo2.bar = ["z", "q"]
some_method(foo2)
foo2.bar.should == ["z", "q", "a"]

# TODO: Cover situation when foo.bar is nil since it is available as attr_accessor 
# and can be set from outside of the instance
```

*** EDITED After Comments Below ****

```
foo = Foo.new
bar = mock
foo.should_receive(:bar).and_return bar
bar.should_receive(:<<).with("a")
some_method(foo)
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I might have over-simplified my example too much.  There is a dependency on an external class in my real code.  Good answer though.

Comment: This also works well for stubbing (and set an expectation for) a `has_and_belongs_to_many` (HABTM) association. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Example from docs:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames

```
double.should_receive(:<<).with("illegal value").once.and_raise(ArgumentError)
```

Comment: So in Lynn's example, it will be `foo.should_receive(:<<).with("a")`

Comment: @PrakashMurthy: In this case, though, foo isn't receiving the <<, bar is.